# Questions that are opinion based?

Tags: discussion

I have a question that I was asked at an interview recently for an IT support job. I wanted to ask the same question somewhere on Stack Overflow but the answers will be completely opinionated and there will be no right or wrong answer.

I'm simply curious to see what other professionals would have suggested in the same situation. Is there a place on Stack Overflow for this?

Comment: "Is there a place on SO for this?" - That would be chat. But you need to pick the room very carefully as some (if not most) of the rooms don't take too kindly to outsiders barging in and dumping questions.

Answer (score 0):

There is a Proposal on Area 51 :

**[Engineering Careers](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/88569/engineering-careers)**

Prefect place for such questions.